# How can a file be launched by a Windows Store app with a specific program?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

How can a Windows Store app launch a file (probably using `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync`) with a specific program (with a given .exe path) without the user seeing an application picker?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a programming question. See [faq] and [ask]

Comment: @SonerGönül Yes it is, I want to do this from code.

Comment: this is just speculation on my part, but given the attitude microsoft seems to have toward the windows store, they don't want you launching exes from your windows store app

Comment: @SamIam Frankly I agree, I just wish they'd make in app advertising available for winforms so I can make proper programs.